# Whatsapp Business API custom fields for webhooks

Tags: webhooks, whatsapp, whatsapp-cloud-api

When sending messages through the cloud Whatsapp Business API, is there a way to send custom fields that will be returned in the webhook notification?

Apart from saving the ID received in the response when sending the message, I could not find a way to connect between the sent message and the returned webhook.